# Store a phone number with a custom label in call log and then call it with my app

Tags: android, label, call, broadcast, receiver

I have an application which uses the Agora library to facilitate a videochat between two parties.

What I want to do is to store the number that calls in the phone's call log, and then, when the user goes into the call log and presses on that number, that number to be passed into my app and used inside my app to call the respective user.

Here's how I currently log the number that is calling the user:

```
@Override
        public void onInviteReceived(final String channelName, final String contactPhone, int uid, final String s2) { //call out other remote receiver
            Log.i(TAG, "onInviteReceived  channelName = " + channelName + " contactPhone = " + contactPhone);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    CallExtra callExtra = gson.fromJson(s2, CallExtra.class);

                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_LABEL, "FairyApp");
                    values.put(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME, "FairyApp");
                    values.put(CallLog.Calls.TYPE, CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE);
                    values.put(CallLog.Calls.DATE, System.currentTimeMillis());
                    values.put(CallLog.Calls.DURATION, 50);
                    values.put(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, contactPhone);

                    getContentResolver().insert(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

As you can see, I've just hardcoded the information just to see if it works, and indeed it does - the number is being recorded into the call log of the phone (obviously, I took care of the permissions to do this already).

Then, I created a broadcast receiver that intercepts an intent of type `android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` , in order to intercept the user calling that number and redirecting him or her to my app and then initiate the call from there.

Here's how the Broadcast Receiver looks in the AndroidManifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".broadcastreceivers.OutgoingCallReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Here's what the Receiver currently does (it's hardcoded, for now):

```
public class OutgoingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
    if (phoneNumber.equals("4444")){
        context.startActivity(new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class));
    }
}
```

}

So, it basically intercepts the intent to call, gets the phone number, and if the phone number is "4444", then it goes into my HomeActivity.

This works.

The problem that I'm having is trying to save a "label" for the stored number - I want to store an information that "this number is of type "MyApp"" and then, when the user presses to call that number from the phone's call log, I want to use that information in my Broadcast Receiver and check "if this is type "MyApp" then open my HomeActivity, else just ignore this broadcast".

So, my question is - how do I store a label into the call log, or some custom piece of information that I can then use in my Broadcast Receiver to identify calls that "belong" to my application?

Thank you.